# Creating JSON-LD property with not yet defined type

Tags: json-ld

I am having some trouble figuring out how to define the `@id` or `@type` for properties whose types have not yet been defined by resources like schema.org.

For example, I'd like to create a location that consists of a WGS84 point (lat/lon/alt) and an error bound around that point (in this case an error cylinder, but I'd be fine with any sort of error at this point).

What I have so far is:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "latitude": {
      "@id":"http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#lat",
      "@type":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float",
    },
    "longitude": {
      "@id":"http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#long",
      "@type":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float",
    },
    "altitude": {
      "@id":"http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#alt",
      "@type":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float",
    },
    "errorRadius":???,
    "errorHalfHeight":???,
  }
}
```

I can't seem to find anything that (a) describes shapes generically, particularly circles and (b) describes the concept of an error bound. I want to be able to say that the location of whatever I'm describing is within a 5 meter radius of the point, and within a 10 meter height of the point.

In addition to this specific question, I'm curious if there's a good way in general to define new concepts that have not yet been defined by things like popolo, schema.org, foaf, w3, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The challenge to find terms describing aspects of a domain that can't be found in a vocabulary at hand (schema.org in your case) can be formalized like this:

1. Search well-known catalogues of vocabularies like [vocab.cc](http://vocab.cc/) and [lov](http://lov.okfn.org/dataset/lov/)
2. Come up with your own description if you

For example, I have reached 2. with the description of legal forms, so I created the [legal forms vocab](https://github.com/n-fuse/legal-form-vocab).

If you do not want to put so much effort in it, you also can just coin the term in your context like this:

```
"errorRadius":{
  "@id":"http://yourdomain.com/schema/vocab#errorRadius",
  "@type":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer",
},
"errorHalfHeight":{
  "@id":"http://yourdomain.com/schema/vocab#errorHalfHeight",
  "@type":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer",
}
```

In this example, I coined `http://yourdomain.com/schema/vocab` as the base namespace for the domain I want to model.

Side note: I don't think that 'error' is the best term here, wouldn't be something like 'tolerance' or 'inaccuracy' be better?

Second side note: You are not required to define the type of simple XSD types when you use JSON-LD because they can be derived from the way you can express decimals, integers and booleans in JSON.